# iText LocationTextExtractionStrategy/HorizontalTextExtractionStrategy splits text into single characters

Tags: pdf, itext

I used a extended version of LocationTextExtractionStrategy to extract connected texts of a pdf and their positions/sizes. I did this by using the locationalResult. This worked well until I tested a [pdf](https://www.dropbox.com/s/iyo9c3hp6qr43u8/qq-test4802_creo3_ttf.pdf?dl=0) containing texts with a different font (ttf). Suddenly these texts are splitted into single characters or small fragments.

> For example "Detail" is not any more one object within the locationalResult list but splitted into six items (D, e, t, a, i, l)

I tried using the [HorizontalTextExtractionStrategy](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext5/blob/master/src/main/java/mkl/testarea/itext5/extract/HorizontalTextExtractionStrategy.java) by making the getLocationalResult method public:

```
public List<TextChunk> GetLocationalResult()
{
    return (List<TextChunk>)locationalResultField.GetValue(this);
}
```

and using the PdfReaderContentParser to extract the texts:

```
reader = new PdfReader("some_pdf");
PdfReaderContentParser parser = new PdfReaderContentParser(reader);
var strategy = parser.ProcessContent(i, HorizontalTextExtractionStrategy());

foreach (HorizontalTextExtractionStrategy.HorizontalTextChunk chunk in strategy.GetLocationalResult())
{
    // Do something with the chunk     
}
```

but this also returns the same result.
Is there any other way to extract connected texts from a pdf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After debugging deep into the iTextSharp library I figured out that my texts are drawn with the TJ operator as mkl also mentioned.

```
[<0027> -0.2<00280037> 0.2<0024002c> 0.2<002f> -0.2<0003>] TJ
```

iText processes these texts not as a single `PdfString` but as an array of `PdfObjects` which ends up in calling `renderListener.RenderText(renderInfo)` for each `PdfString` item in it (see [ShowTextArray](https://github.com/itext/itextsharp/blob/d2657a5a1ab481f632e6d1f0eebf9d96bed087d5/src/core/iTextSharp/text/pdf/parser/PdfContentStreamProcessor.cs#L494) class and [DisplayPdfString](https://github.com/itext/itextsharp/blob/d2657a5a1ab481f632e6d1f0eebf9d96bed087d5/src/core/iTextSharp/text/pdf/parser/PdfContentStreamProcessor.cs#L332) method). In the `RenderText` method however the information about the relation of the pdf strings within the array got lost and every item is added to `locationalResult` as an independent object.

As my goal is to extract the "argument of a single text drawing instruction" I extended the `PdfContentStreamProcessor` class about a new method `ProcessTexts` which returns a list of these atomic strings. My workaround is not very pretty as I had to copy paste some private fields and methods from the [original source](https://github.com/itext/itextsharp/blob/d2657a5a1ab481f632e6d1f0eebf9d96bed087d5/src/core/iTextSharp/text/pdf/parser/PdfContentStreamProcessor.cs) but it works for me.

```
class PdfContentStreamProcessorEx : PdfContentStreamProcessor
{
    private IDictionary<int, CMapAwareDocumentFont> cachedFonts = new Dictionary<int, CMapAwareDocumentFont>();
    private ResourceDictionary resources = new ResourceDictionary();
    private CMapAwareDocumentFont font = null;

    public PdfContentStreamProcessorEx(IRenderListener renderListener) : base(renderListener)
    {
    }

    public List<string> ProcessTexts(byte[] contentBytes, PdfDictionary resources)
    {
        this.resources.Push(resources);
        var texts = new List<string>();
        PRTokeniser tokeniser = new PRTokeniser(new RandomAccessFileOrArray(new RandomAccessSourceFactory().CreateSource(contentBytes)));
        PdfContentParser ps = new PdfContentParser(tokeniser);
        List<PdfObject> operands = new List<PdfObject>();
        while (ps.Parse(operands).Count > 0)
        {
            PdfLiteral oper = (PdfLiteral)operands[operands.Count - 1];
            if ("Tj".Equals(oper.ToString()))
            {
                texts.Add(getText((PdfString)operands[0]));
            }
            else if ("TJ".Equals(oper.ToString()))
            {
                string text = string.Empty;
                foreach (PdfObject entryObj in (PdfArray)operands[0])
                {
                    if (entryObj is PdfString)
                    {
                        text += getText((PdfString)entryObj);
                    }
                }
                texts.Add(text);
            }
            else if ("Tf".Equals(oper.ToString()))
            {
                PdfName fontResourceName = (PdfName)operands[0];
                float size = ((PdfNumber)operands[1]).FloatValue;

                PdfDictionary fontsDictionary = resources.GetAsDict(PdfName.FONT);
                CMapAwareDocumentFont _font;
                PdfObject fontObject = fontsDictionary.Get(fontResourceName);
                if (fontObject is PdfDictionary)
                    _font = GetFont((PdfDictionary)fontObject);
                else
                    _font = GetFont((PRIndirectReference)fontObject);

                font = _font;
            }
        }

        this.resources.Pop();

        return texts;
    }

    string getText(PdfString @in)
    {
        byte[] bytes = @in.GetBytes();
        return font.Decode(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    }

    private CMapAwareDocumentFont GetFont(PRIndirectReference ind)
    {
        CMapAwareDocumentFont font;
        cachedFonts.TryGetValue(ind.Number, out font);
        if (font == null)
        {
            font = new CMapAwareDocumentFont(ind);
            cachedFonts[ind.Number] = font;
        }
        return font;
    }

    private CMapAwareDocumentFont GetFont(PdfDictionary fontResource)
    {
        return new CMapAwareDocumentFont(fontResource);
    }

    private class ResourceDictionary : PdfDictionary
    {
        private IList<PdfDictionary> resourcesStack = new List<PdfDictionary>();

        virtual public void Push(PdfDictionary resources)
        {
            resourcesStack.Add(resources);
        }

        virtual public void Pop()
        {
            resourcesStack.RemoveAt(resourcesStack.Count - 1);
        }

        public override PdfObject GetDirectObject(PdfName key)
        {
            for (int i = resourcesStack.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                PdfDictionary subResource = resourcesStack[i];
                if (subResource != null)
                {
                    PdfObject obj = subResource.GetDirectObject(key);
                    if (obj != null) return obj;
                }
            }
            return base.GetDirectObject(key); // shouldn't be necessary, but just in case we've done something crazy
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I used a extended version of `LocationTextExtractionStrategy` to extract connected texts of a pdf and their positions/sizes. I did this by using the `locationalResult`. This worked well until I tested a pdf containing texts with a different font (ttf). Suddenly these texts are splitted into single characters or small fragments.

This problem is due to wrong expectations concerning the contents of the `LocationTextExtractionStrategy.locationalResult` private list member variable.

This list of `TextChunk` instances contains the pieces of text as they were forwarded to the strategy from the parsing framework (or probably as they were preprocessed by some filter class), and the framework forwards each single string it encounters in a content stream separately.

Thus, if a seemingly connected word in the content stream actually is drawn using multiple strings, you get multiple `TextChunk` instances for it.

There actually is some "intelligence" in the method `getResultantText` joining these chunks properly, adding a space where necessary and so on.

In case of your document, "DETAIL " usually is drawn like this:

```
[<0027> -0.2<00280037> 0.2<0024002c> 0.2<002f> -0.2<0003>] TJ
```

As you see there are slight text insertion point moves between 'D' and 'E', 'T' and 'A', 'I' and 'L', and 'L' and ' '. (Such mini moves usually represent kerning.) Thus, you'll get individual `TextChunk` instances for 'D', 'ET', 'AI', and 'L '.

Admittedly, the `LocationTextExtractionStrategy.locationalResult` member is not very well documented; but as it is a private member, this IMHO is forgivable.

---

That *this worked well* for many documents is due to many PDF creators not applying kerning and simply drawing connected text using single string objects.

---

The `HorizontalTextExtractionStrategy` is derived from the `LocationTextExtractionStrategy` and mainly differs from it in the way it arranges the `TextChunk` instances to a single string. Thus, you'll see the same fragmentation here.

---

> Is there any other way to extract connected texts from a pdf?

If you want "connected texts" as in "atomic string objects in the content stream", you already have them.

If you want "connected texts" as in "visually connected texts, no matter where the constituent letters are drawn in the content stream", you have to glue those `TextChunk` instances together like the `LocationTextExtractionStrategy` and `HorizontalTextExtractionStrategy` do in `getResultantText` in combination with the comparison methods in their respective `TextChunkLocationDefaultImp` and `HorizontalTextChunkLocation` implementations.

Comment: Using the term "connected texts" I meant "atomic string objects in the content" but as you can read in my answer I don't already have them. So therefor didn't accept as answer. Thank you anyway for the good explanation!

Comment: @seeb A pdf string is delimited by angled or round brackets (`<...>` or `(...)`) which is the "atomic string objects" I meant. You seem to be looking for "argument of a *single text drawing instruction*" (which in case of **TJ** is an array of strings and numbers). Depending on the actual numbers in that array the constituent strings may be drawn quite far from each other.

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I am looking for. Sorry for the confusing terms I used. I am not so familiar with the pdf terminology.

Comment: @seeb ok, as you have seen yourself, there is nothing in the iText parser framework that signals you that datum out of the box. But I really wonder about the purpose of wanting to get such text units because on the one hand `[(A) 7 (B)] TJ` is essentially equivalent to `[(A) 7] TJ (B) Tj` and on the other hand the result of `[(A) -18000 (B)] TJ` does not really look connected on the page. (The latter is not hypothetical, it is a typical output of iText PdfCleanUp.)

Comment: In my case I have one main CAD application that exports the PDFs and I can rely on that those text units are meant to be connected (at least at the moment). I am aware of the risk but trying to figure out which text are meant to be connected by analyzing gaps and positions will be even less stable I think. I can't find  `[(A) -18000 (B)] TJ` in my pdf. How did you convert it to ASCII?

Comment: *How did you convert it to ASCII?* - There are two syntactically different types of Java strings, those in round brackets and those in angled brackets. In round brackets you immediately get the glyph codes. In angled brackets you get their hex encoding. The encoding of the glyph codes depends on the way the font in question is used. This encoding *can* be ASCII'ish (e.g. **WinAnsiEncoding**) or not. The encoding depends on the way the font in question is addressed in the PDF.